# Java Servlets (Session Management)

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a Web Project where index.html calls=>First(Servlet), has a hyperlink (called "click here"), that calls=>Welcome(Second Servlet), which has a hyperlink (called "go back") too

1. Html file takes input some text and has a submit button. When I click on Submit, First(Servlet File) gets called and displays some hyperlink, and also sets an attribute to store the text that was input in html file.
2. In First(Servlet), when I click on hyperlink I am directed to Welcome(Servlet File). The text input is displayed here using getattribute() method through HTTPSession. When I click go back hyperlink, I am redirected ti First(Servlet), and the navigation from First to Welcome and Welcome to First can go on, if you click the respective hyperlinks.
3. But, only concern is the text that is displayed on Welcome happens only once. As soon as I click go back, i cannot maintain retrieve the input text, which is lost. And so, on click of "click here" hyperlink the second time, I get navigated to Welcome, but the text value displayed is null.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You can just try to create a simple model in which you define important elements that you do not want to lose and then give access to it to each of your Servlets. I would recommend this as an optional solution to your problem.

Best regards **Aoma**